# In Bash, how can I check if a string begins with some value?

Tags: string, bash, comparison

I would like to check if a string begins with "node" e.g. "node001". Something like

```
if [ $HOST == node* ]
  then
  echo yes
fi
```

How can I do it correctly?

---

I further need to combine expressions to check if `HOST` is either "user1" or begins with "node":

```
if [ [[ $HOST == user1 ]] -o [[ $HOST == node* ]] ];
then
echo yes
fi

> > > -bash: [: too many arguments
```

How can I do it correctly?

Comment: Don't be too tempted to combine expressions. It may look uglier to have two separate conditionals, though you can give better error messages and make your script easier to debug. Also I would avoid the bash features. The switch is the way to go.

Answer (score 1550, accepted):

This snippet on the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) says:

```
# The == comparison operator behaves differently within a double-brackets
# test than within single brackets.

[[ $a == z* ]]   # True if $a starts with a "z" (wildcard matching).
[[ $a == "z*" ]] # True if $a is equal to z* (literal matching).
```

So you had it *nearly* correct; you needed *double* brackets, not single brackets.

---

With regards to your second question, you can write it this way:

```
HOST=user1
if  [[ $HOST == user1 ]] || [[ $HOST == node* ]] ;
then
    echo yes1
fi

HOST=node001
if [[ $HOST == user1 ]] || [[ $HOST == node* ]] ;
then
    echo yes2
fi
```

Which will echo

```
yes1
yes2
```

Bash's `if` syntax is hard to get used to (IMO).

Comment: For regex do you mean [[ $a =~ ^z.* ]] ?

Comment: So is there a functional difference between `[[ $a == z* ]]` and `[[ $a == "z*" ]]`? In other words: do they work differently? And what specifically do you mean when you say "$a is equal to z*"?

Comment: You don't need the statement separator ";" if you put "then" on its own line

Comment: @NielsBom: the first one will match any string starting with `z`, the second will only match a literal `z*`.

Comment: Just for completeness: To check if a string ENDS with ... : `[[ $a == *com ]]`

Comment: This is not useful without a discussion about how to deal with shell expansion of the wildcard.

Comment: The ABS is an unfortunate choice of references -- it's very much the W3Schools of bash, full of outdated content and bad-practice examples; the freenode #bash channel has been trying to discourage its use [at least since 2008](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/abs). Any chance of repointing at [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)? (I'd also have suggested the Bash-Hackers' wiki, but it's been down for a bit now).

Comment: Does this not need quotes around the lhs (eg. `[[ "$a" == z* ]]`)? If not, why? Wouldn't an empty `a` cause problems?

Comment: No word splitting or glob expansion will be done for `[[`, so you don't need to quote `a$`. [Reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).

Comment: Please note that double brackets are bash specific and not POSIX compliant. They won't work the same way in other shells.

Comment: Is there any functional difference between `[[ $HOST == user1 ]] || [[ $HOST == node* ]]` and `[[ $HOST == user1 || $HOST == node* ]]`?

Comment: If your pattern contains a space, replace the space with `[[:space:]]`, e.g., `if [[ "${a}" != test[[:space:]]host* ]]`

Comment: In case you need to have whitespaces, you may wrap the value with single quotes
`if [[ $3 == 'list naptrrecord'* ]]
        then
            echo "<object class=\"NAPTRRecord\">"
        fi`

Comment: why is it so easy, _really bash, i'm disappointed that i will be able to remember this and use it without checking the docs_.

Comment: A simple shell (not bash) test like `[ -z "${HOST##user*}" ]` would be enough... why all this complicated bash things?

Comment: What about [],  single bracket? [ $a == str... ]

Comment: rationale: wildcards will only be in effect if the value is given without quotes.

Comment: man, bash is such a train wreck, hard to wrap you're head around some of the more ridiculous aspects of it. trying to make this work when I want to test if a string starts with a `#`, no luck so far

Comment: Why `[[ $a == "#*" ]]` does not work? How to fix? Note: the `if [[ $a == \#* ]]` is working.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I've overlooked: `[[ $a == "z*" ]]` is true if `$a` is _equal_ to `z*`.

Answer (score 379):

If you're using a recent version of Bash (v3+), I suggest the Bash regex comparison operator `=~`, for example,

```
if [[ "$HOST" =~ ^user.* ]]; then
    echo "yes"
fi
```

---

To match `this or that` in a regex, use `|`, for example,

```
if [[ "$HOST" =~ ^user.*|^host1 ]]; then
    echo "yes"
fi
```

Note - this is 'proper' regular expression syntax.

- `user*` means `use` and zero-or-more occurrences of `r`, so `use` and `userrrr` will match.
- `user.*` means `user` and zero-or-more occurrences of any character, so `user1`, `userX` will match.
- `^user.*` means match the pattern `user.*` at the begin of $HOST.

If you're not familiar with regular expression syntax, try referring to [this resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Note that the Bash `=~` operator only does regular expression matching when the right hand side is **UNQUOTED**. If you do quote the right hand side, "any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string.". You should not quote the right hand side even when doing parameter expansion.

Comment: Thanks, Brabster! I added to the original post a new question about how to combine expressions in if cluase.

Comment: Its a pity that the accepted answer does not says anything about the syntax of regular expression.

Comment: **FYI the Bash `=~` operator only does regular expression matching when the right hand side is UNQUOTED. If you do quote the right hand side "Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string."** (1.) make sure to always put the regular expressions on the right un-quoted and (2.) if you store your regular expression in a variable, make sure to NOT quote the right hand side when you do parameter expansion.

Answer (score 279):

I always try to stick with POSIX `sh` instead of using Bash extensions, since one of the major points of scripting is portability (besides **connecting** programs, not replacing them).

In `sh`, there is an easy way to check for an "is-prefix" condition.

```
case $HOST in node*)
    # Your code here
esac
```

Given how old, arcane and crufty sh is (and Bash is not the cure: It's more complicated, less consistent and less portable), I'd like to point out a very nice functional aspect: While some syntax elements like `case` are built-in, the resulting constructs are no different than any other job. They can be composed in the same way:

```
if case $HOST in node*) true;; *) false;; esac; then
    # Your code here
fi
```

Or even shorter

```
if case $HOST in node*) ;; *) false;; esac; then
    # Your code here
fi
```

Or *even* shorter (just to present `!` as a language element -- but this is bad style now)

```
if ! case $HOST in node*) false;; esac; then
    # Your code here
fi
```

If you like being explicit, build your own language element:

```
beginswith() { case $2 in "$1"*) true;; *) false;; esac; }
```

Isn't this actually quite nice?

```
if beginswith node "$HOST"; then
    # Your code here
fi
```

And since `sh` is basically only jobs and string-lists (and internally processes, out of which jobs are composed), we can now even do some light functional programming:

```
beginswith() { case $2 in "$1"*) true;; *) false;; esac; }
checkresult() { if [ $? = 0 ]; then echo TRUE; else echo FALSE; fi; }

all() {
    test=$1; shift
    for i in "$@"; do
        $test "$i" || return
    done
}

all "beginswith x" x xy xyz ; checkresult  # Prints TRUE
all "beginswith x" x xy abc ; checkresult  # Prints FALSE
```

This is elegant. Not that I'd advocate using `sh` for anything serious -- it breaks all too quickly on real world requirements (no lambdas, so we must use strings. But nesting function calls with strings is not possible, pipes are not possible, etc.)

Comment: +1 Not only is this portable, it's also readable, idiomatic, and elegant (for shell script). It also extends naturally to multiple patterns; `case $HOST in user01 | node* ) ...`

Comment: Is there a name for this type of code formatting?
`if case $HOST in node*) true;; *) false;; esac; then`

I've seen it here and there, to my eye it looks kinda scrunched up.

Comment: @NielsBom I don't know what exactly you mean by formatting, but my point was that shell code is very much *composable*. Becaues `case` commands are commands, they can go inside `if ... then`.

Comment: I don't even see why it's composable, I don't understand enough shell script for that :-)

My question is about how this code uses non-matched parentheses and double semicolons. It doesn't look anything like the shell script I've seen before, but I may be used to seeing bash script more than sh script so that might be it.

Comment: Note: It should be `beginswith() { case "$2" in "$1"*) true;; *) false;; esac; }` otherwise if `$1` has a literal `*` or `?` it might give wrong answer.

Comment: @LLFourn: Thanks! You are right. I corrected it. But you don't need quotes around `$2`.

Comment: While the shell's `case` syntax may seem arcane and bewildering at first, you get used to it quickly. You should definitely acquire a basic familiarity with the construct in order to be able to read scripts written by others, even if you don't plan to use it yourself. (Personally, I tend to favor it over `if [[ $string something...` in all its myriad slightly different variants. The POSIX compatibility is a nice bonus.)

Comment: +1 Awesome solution, especially the case. One hint: pipes with functions are possible. You can use read inside the function to read or cat to read the input.

Comment: @LLFourn @ Jo So - May I ask why quotes around $2 is not necessary? I think whenever content contains special characters or (more than one) spaces, we need the quotes otherwise it causes error. Thanks for this great answer. It is my favourite.

Comment: I know about when to use quotes in case statements now. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/150246 . May I ask why in your function `beginswith`, you can write `true` and `false` without echo. And they can be caught by the callers. I am trying to understand this syntax. Thank you.

Comment: Somehow from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431909/returning-a-boolean-from-a-bash-function#comment21379873_5431932) I understand now. They are essentially the exit statuses, which are the last command in the function. A single `true` statement equals to `return 0`, while `false` equals to `return 1`. As these are exit statuses, they cannot be captured by variable assignment, nor by echo, etc. Yet they are cool for places which check the exit status, such as `if` and boolean expressions. Just want to quote [three ways for func](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8743103/1884546).

Answer (score 117):

You can select just the part of the string you want to check:

```
if [ "${HOST:0:4}" = user ]
```

For your follow-up question, you could use an [OR](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html):

```
if [[ "$HOST" == user1 || "$HOST" == node* ]]
```

Comment: You should doublequote `${HOST:0:4}`

Comment: @Jo So: What is the reason?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, try `HOST='a b'; if [ ${HOST:0:4} = user ] ; then echo YES ; fi`

Comment: Alternatively, double brackets: `if [[ ${HOST:0:4} = user ]]`

Comment: @martin clayton Please post the whole if expression.

Comment: If you want "ends with", then compare with "${HOST:0:-4}" so it will detect stuff like "dev-user" or "prod-user", for example.

Answer (score 65):

I prefer the other methods already posted, but some people like to use:

```
case "$HOST" in 
    user1|node*) 
            echo "yes";;
        *)
            echo "no";;
esac
```

**Edit:**

I've added your alternates to the case statement above

In your edited version you have too many brackets. It should look like this:

```
if [[ $HOST == user1 || $HOST == node* ]];
```

Comment: Thanks, Dennis! I added to the original post a new question about how to combine expressions in if cluase.

Comment: "some people like..." : this one is more portable across versions and shells.

Comment: With case statements you can leave away the quotes around the variable since no word splitting occurs. I know it's pointless and inconsistent but I do like to leave away the quotes there to make it locally more visually appealing.

Comment: And in my case, I had to leave away the quotes before ):  "/*") did not work, /*) did. (I'm looking for strings starting with /, i.e., absolute paths)

Answer (score 47):

While I find most answers here quite correct, many of them contain unnecessary Bashisms. [POSIX parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_006_002) gives you all you need:

```
[ "${host#user}" != "${host}" ]
```

and

```
[ "${host#node}" != "${host}" ]
```

`${var#expr}` strips the smallest prefix matching `expr` from `${var}` and returns that. Hence if `${host}` does **not** start with `user` (`node`), `${host#user}` (`${host#node}`) is the same as `${host}`.

`expr` allows [`fnmatch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fnmatch.html) wildcards, thus `${host#node??}` and friends also work.

Comment: I'd argue that the bashism `[[ $host == user* ]]` might be necessary, since it's far more readable than `[ "${host#user}" != "${host}" ]`. As such granted that you control the environment where the script is executed (target the latest versions of `bash`), the former is preferable.

Comment: @x-yuri Frankly, I'd simply pack this away into a `has_prefix()` function and never look at it again.

Answer (score 40):

Since `#` has a meaning in Bash, I got to the following solution.

In addition I like better to pack strings with "" to overcome spaces, etc.

```
A="#sdfs"
if [[ "$A" == "#"* ]];then
    echo "Skip comment line"
fi
```

Comment: thanks, I was also wondering how to match a string starting with `blah:`, looks like this is the answer!

Comment: `case $A in "#"*) echo "Skip comment line";; esac` is both shorter and more portable.

Comment: is this a reply to the question? I dont see any sdfs...

Comment: KansaiRobot, it demonstrates how to use * in cash string compare. everyone should replade "sdfs" with the string he wants to compare

Answer (score 16):

Adding a tiny bit more syntax detail to Mark Rushakoff's highest rank answer.

The expression

```
$HOST == node*
```

Can also be written as

```
$HOST == "node"*
```

The effect is the same. Just make sure the wildcard is outside the quoted text. If the wildcard is *inside* the quotes it will be interpreted literally (i.e. not as a wildcard).

Answer (score 13):

Keep it simple

```bash
word="appel"

if [[ $word = a* ]]
then
  echo "Starts with a"
else
  echo "No match"
fi
```

Answer (score 8):

@OP, for both your questions you can use case/esac:

```
string="node001"
case "$string" in
  node*) echo "found";;
  * ) echo "no node";;
esac
```

Second question

```
case "$HOST" in
 node*) echo "ok";;
 user) echo "ok";;
esac

case "$HOST" in
 node*|user) echo "ok";;
esac
```

*Or* Bash 4.0

```
case "$HOST" in
 user) ;&
 node*) echo "ok";;
esac
```

Comment: Note that `;&` is only available in Bash >= 4.

Answer (score 6):

```
if [ [[ $HOST == user1 ]] -o [[ $HOST == node* ]] ];
then
echo yes
fi
```

doesn't work, because all of `[`, `[[`, and `test` recognize the same nonrecursive grammar. See section *CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS* on your Bash man page.

As an aside, the SUSv3 says

> The KornShell-derived conditional command (double bracket **[[]]**) was removed from the shell command language description in an early proposal.  Objections were raised that the real problem is misuse of the *test* command (**[**), and putting it into the shell is the wrong way to fix the problem.  Instead, proper documentation and a new shell reserved word (**!**) are sufficient.
>
> Tests that require multiple *test* operations can be done at the shell level using individual invocations of the *test* command and shell logicals, rather than using the error-prone **-o** flag of *test*.

You'd need to write it this way, but *test* doesn't support it:

```
if [ $HOST == user1 -o $HOST == node* ];
then
echo yes
fi
```

*test* uses *=* for string equality, and more importantly it doesn't support pattern matching.

`case` / `esac` has good support for pattern matching:

```
case $HOST in
user1|node*) echo yes ;;
esac
```

It has the added benefit that it doesn't depend on Bash, and the syntax is portable. From the *[Single Unix Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification)*, *The Shell Command Language*:

```
case word in
    [(]pattern1) compound-list;;
    [[(]pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list;;] ...
    [[(]pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list]
esac
```

Comment: `[` and `test` are Bash builtins as well as external programs. Try `type -a [`.

Comment: Many thanks for explaining the problems with the "compound or", @just somebody - was looking precisely for something like that! Cheers! PS note (unrelated to OP): `if [ -z $aa -or -z $bb ]` ; ... gives "*bash: [: -or: binary operator expected*" ; however `if [ -z "$aa" -o -z "$bb" ] ; ...` passes.

Answer (score 5):

**`grep`**

Forgetting performance, this is POSIX and looks nicer than `case` solutions:

```
mystr="abcd"
if printf '%s' "$mystr" | grep -Eq '^ab'; then
  echo matches
fi
```

Explanation:

- `printf '%s'` to prevent `printf` from expanding backslash escapes: *[Bash printf literal verbatim string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423203/bash-printf-literal-verbatim-string/40423558#40423558)*
- `grep -q` prevents echo of matches to stdout: *[How to check if a file contains a specific string using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287861/how-to-check-if-a-file-contains-a-specific-string-using-bash)*
- `grep -E` enables extended regular expressions, which we need for the `^`

Answer (score 3):

I tweaked @markrushakoff's answer to make it a callable function:

```
function yesNo {
  # Prompts user with $1, returns true if response starts with y or Y or is empty string
  read -e -p "
$1 [Y/n] " YN

  [[ "$YN" == y* || "$YN" == Y* || "$YN" == "" ]]
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$ if yesNo "asfd"; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi

asfd [Y/n] y
true

$ if yesNo "asfd"; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi

asfd [Y/n] Y
true

$ if yesNo "asfd"; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi

asfd [Y/n] yes
true

$ if yesNo "asfd"; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi

asfd [Y/n]
true

$ if yesNo "asfd"; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi

asfd [Y/n] n
false

$ if yesNo "asfd"; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi

asfd [Y/n] ddddd
false
```

Here is a more complex version that provides for a specified default value:

```
function toLowerCase {
  echo "$1" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
}

function yesNo {
  # $1: user prompt
  # $2: default value (assumed to be Y if not specified)
  # Prompts user with $1, using default value of $2, returns true if response starts with y or Y or is empty string

  local DEFAULT=yes
  if [ "$2" ]; then local DEFAULT="$( toLowerCase "$2" )"; fi
  if [[ "$DEFAULT" == y* ]]; then
    local PROMPT="[Y/n]"
  else
    local PROMPT="[y/N]"
  fi
  read -e -p "
$1 $PROMPT " YN

  YN="$( toLowerCase "$YN" )"
  { [ "$YN" == "" ] && [[ "$PROMPT" = *Y* ]]; } || [[ "$YN" = y* ]]
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$ if yesNo "asfd" n; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi

asfd [y/N]
false

$ if yesNo "asfd" n; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi

asfd [y/N] y
true

$ if yesNo "asfd" y; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi

asfd [Y/n] n
false
```