# Get commit message in Git hook

Tags: git, hook

I would like to check the commit message before Git commit.

I use a pre-commit hook to do that, but I couldn't find the way to get the commit message in the *.git/pre-commit* script.
How could I get it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the `pre-commit` hook, the commit message usually hasn't been created yet <sup>1</sup>.  You probably want to use one of the `prepare-commit-msg` or `commit-msg` hooks instead.  There's a [nice section in Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on the order in which these hooks are run, and what you typically might do with them.

<sub>1. The exception is that the committer might have supplied a commit message with `-m`, but the message still isn't accessible to the `pre-commit` hook, whereas it is to `prepare-commit-msg` or `commit-msg`</sub>

Comment: Please note that these are client side scripts, for server side script, one may need to use `pre-receive`.

Comment: ` the commit message hasn't been created yet` yes it has .. when the user typed `git commit -m "foobar"`

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman - OK, fair enough - I've reworded the answer and added a footnote about that.

Answer (score 24):

I implemented this in the `commit-msg` hook. See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

```
commit-msg

This hook is invoked by git commit, and can be bypassed with the --no-verify option.
It takes a single parameter, the name of the file that holds the proposed commit log message.
Exiting with a non-zero status causes the git commit to abort.
```

Under `my_git_project/.git/hooks`, I added the file `commit-msg` (has to be this name). I added the following Bash contents inside this file which did the validation.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
INPUT_FILE=$1
START_LINE=`head -n1 $INPUT_FILE`
PATTERN="^(MYPROJ)-[[:digit:]]+: "
if ! [[ "$START_LINE" =~ $PATTERN ]]; then
  echo "Bad commit message, see example: MYPROJ-123: commit message"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Its not working. I can't get commit message in commit-msg hook.                COMMIT_FILE=$1                                                                               COMMIT_MSG=$(cat $1)

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be commit-msg instead of commit.msg ?

Comment: file has to be named commit-msg, not commit.msg.

Comment: how do i get commit message in variable ? cat $1 is not working...

Comment: It works, thank you, but only if I get rid of the quotes in PATTERN, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172352/in-bash-how-can-i-check-if-a-string-begins-with-some-value#comment84627580_2172365.
`PATTERN=^\[.*-\d*\].*`

Answer (score 3):

The hook name should be:

`commit-msg` , otherwise it won't get invoked:

Comment: yes and apparently the commit message is the first argument passed to `commit-msg`, which is also the same as the contents of the file `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`

Comment: Yes, it also says so in the (sample) file *commit-msg.sample*, line 9: *'To enable this hook, rename this file to "commit-msg".'*

Answer (score 3):

I have created a *commit-msg* script in Bash having the commit syntax <CURRENT_BRANCH_NAME>-<4_DIGIT_TICKETID>-<COMMIT_DECRIPTION>. This syntax can be used for [Azure DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server) ticket ID-based commits by the developer.

```
#!/bin/sh

# The below input_file is file ".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" where commits are stored
INPUT_FILE=$1

# It will copy the commit string from ".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG"
START_LINE=`head -n1 $INPUT_FILE`

# Initial index value
sum=0

# Add commit in an array variable separated by -
IFS='- ' read -r -a array_value <<< "$START_LINE"

# Count array index
for i in ${!array_value[@]}
do
    sum=`expr $sum + $i`
done

# Verify commit
if [ ${sum} == 3 ]; then

BRANCH_NAME=`git branch | awk '/\*/ { print $2; }'`
TICKET_DIGIT=`awk -F '[0-9]' '{print NF-1}' <<< "${array_value[1]}"`

   if [ ${array_value[0]} != ${BRANCH_NAME} ];  then
        echo "please enter current branch name"
        exit 1
   fi

   if [ "${TICKET_DIGIT}" != "4" ];  then
        echo "INVALID TICKET ID"
        exit 1
   else
      echo "verify ticket ID ${array_value[1]}"
   fi

else
   echo "pattern must be <CURRENT_BRANCH_NAME>-<4_DIGIT_TICKETID>-<COMMIT_DECRIPTION> without space and don't use - in commit_description"
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for the input file head command, this was killing me https://gist.github.com/phillpafford/02437d61a90a8d5f8cd520944a7b618c

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is done by `commit-msg`.
This hook gives us a file which contains the commit message.
Here is a sample to reject a commit in which we have **test** word:

```
declare -r msg=$(< $1);
if grep -i test <<< "$msg" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo you are not allowd to have test commit.
    exit 1;
else
    echo looks good.
    exit 0;
fi
```

So `exit 1` does not allow git to continue and `exit 0` of the hook allows git to continue.

---

Note
Here `$1` is the name of that file which is : `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the commit message from hooks other than `commit-msg`, you can read the file `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`.

Simple Python example: *(Git hooks can run Python with the `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang)*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pathlib import Path

print(Path(".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG").read_text())
```

Just make sure to get the relative path right, based on your current working directory

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following in a `pre-receive` hook (for server side) using Python, and that will display the revision information.

```
import sys
import subprocess
old, new, branch = sys.stdin.read().split()
proc = subprocess.Popen(["git", "rev-list", "--oneline","--first-parent" , "%s..%s" %(old, new)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
commitMessage=str(proc.stdout.readlines()[0])
```