# pre-commit hook to read commit message

Tags: git, github, githooks

How to read commit message from git commit -m "message" using pre-commit hook.
Or Is there any hook that reads commit message.

commit-msg hook can read the message but we need to provide a text file as input which I don't want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get commit message in git hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393178/get-commit-message-in-git-hook)

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve? pre-commit may just be the wrong tool for the job. If you want to evaluate the commit message, `commit-msg` is the more natural place for it.

Comment: You won't *need* to provide a text file as input, it is a possible feature but message template files are in no way mandatory.

Comment: @Mureinik I need to check for errors in commit message. I can check with commit-msg hook, but then my commit message changes to git commit -F filename.

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks it worked for me

Comment: pre-commit hook is executed before the commit, so naturally it cannot access the commit message since it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once git commit -m "message" has been invoked, the message part gets stored in .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG file and commit-msg hook takes this as the input internally.

so you can use git commit -m "message" instead of git commit -F Filepath.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `commit-msg` hook. The `$1` argument there contains the commit message, and if the check you need to perform fails, just return `1` to fail the commit.