# Check a git commit comment before commit (check for the name of the branch in the comment)

Tags: git, phpstorm

Good day!

I want to check if the branch name is present in the comment of commit before commit it.
I'am looking for a phpstorm plugin or other way.
I need to do this on client site.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get commit message in git hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393178/get-commit-message-in-git-hook)

Comment: Oops, I just realized [Keldorn's link that I used for the close op](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452152/check-a-git-commit-comment-before-commit-check-for-the-name-of-the-branch-in-th#comment108706989_61452152) goes to a question that *doesn't* show how to get the current *branch name*. Let me find a secondary link too.

Comment: Note my comment on the second link's question, that `git rev-parse --abbrev-rev HEAD` or `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like what I'm looking for