# using if and a boolean function in bash script: if condition evaluates to false when function returns true

Tags: bash, function

```
is_dir_empty(){

    for file in "$1"
    do
        if [ "$file" != "$1" ]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done
    echo "return 1"
    return 1
}

file="/home/tmp/*.sh"

if is_dir_empty "$file"; then
    echo "empty"
else echo "not empty"
fi
```

it outputs

```
return 1
not empty
```

so is_dir_empty returned 1 but if condition evaluated to false somehow.... why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash functions: return boolean to be used in if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431909/bash-functions-return-boolean-to-be-used-in-if)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because shell scripts follow the Unix convention of expecting utilities to return zero for success and non-zero for failure, so boolean conditions are inverted.

Answer (score 2):

Globs are not expanded in double quotes, so you're always comparing against the literal value `/home/tmp/*.sh`. Unquote `$1` in the for loop, and it'll word split and glob expand into a list of .sh files ([this online tool](http://shellcheck.net) would have pointed this out automatically).

Also, unlike in C, zero is considered success and non-zero failure.

Comment: The online tool looks like it would have been useful, is there an equivalent that is up today?

Comment: @StuartAxon Today there's ShellCheck. It has an online version and can also be installed locally

Answer (score 0):

you can check if a directory is empty by:

```
[ "$(ls -A /path/to/directory)" ] && echo "Not Empty" || echo "Empty"
```