# How to split a array to several based on create date and modified date of .MTS video files

Tags: bash, shell, video, mts

i want to make automatic create folder based on Regularity of current fodler's MTS video files.

i could get some right info by 
declare -a  CreateArray10digits=$(stat -f "%B" *  | cut -c1-10)
declare -a  ModifiedArray10digits=$(stat -f "%m" * | cut -c1-10)

junked file have difference 0second or 1second.

so finally 
clip-1 folder : 00000.MTS   00001.MTS  00002.MTS  00003.MTS  00004.MTS  00005.MTS  00006.MTS  00007.MTS  00008.MTS  00009.MTS  00010.MTS  00011.MTS

clip-2 folder :00012.MTS

clip-3 folder :00013.MTS  00014.MTS

clip-4 folder :00015.MTS

clip-5 fodler :00016.MTS

if there are no Regularity on each MTS file in current folder, then 
just make clip-1 to clip-16 and move to each folder .. that's it

what will be best script for bash shell on a mac ?

================ here my trying code ==============

### # first , get files list as array based on Create-date time(seconds base) for current directory for MTS files

```
declare -a  CreateArray10digits=$(stat -f "%B" *  | cut -c1-10)
```

---

### # make  new array for CreateArray10digits

```
indexOfcreateArray10digits=($CreateArray10digits)
```

---

### # seconds, get files list as array based on Modified-date time for current directory for .MTS files

```
declare -a  ModifiedArray10digits=$(stat -f "%m" * | cut -c1-10)
```

---

### # make new array for ModifiedArray10digits

```
indexOfmodifiedArray10digits=($ModifiedArray10digits)
```

---

### # and  get the array's length for CreateArray10digits

```
indexOfcreateArray10digitsLenth=${#indexOfcreateArray10digits[*]}
```

### indexOfmodifiedArray10digitsLenth=${#indexOfmodifiedArray10digits[*]}

### # make new array for filename list  of current directory

```
declare -a  ArrayFullFileNameWithExtension=$(stat -f "%N" *)
indexOfModifiedArrayFullFileNameWithExtension=($ArrayFullFileNameWithExtension)

declare -a  ArrayFullFileNameWithoutExtension=$(stat -f "%N" * | cut -c1-5 )
indexOfModifiedArrayFullFileNameWithoutExtension=($ArrayFullFileNameWithoutExtension)
```

## finally , i made severals arrays and these array finally have same length

## my code below

```
CNT=$((${#indexOfcreateArray10digits[*]}-1)) # 17-1 = 16
last_file_index=$CNT
current_dir=1
make_clip_dir $current_dir
move_clip 0 $current_dir  # what mean 0 ?  00000.MTS ? 


# when not junked then will be make new folder by for - loop
function make_clip_dir {
    mkdir "clip-$1"
}

# is this move_clip function right ? 
function move_clip {
   mv ${indexOfModifiedArrayFullFileNameWithExtension[$1]} "./clip-$2"
}

# please check below code is right or not .. very i am confused :-) 
    function connected_junks {
    if [[ $((${indexOfcreateArray10digits[$2]} - ${indexOfmodifiedArray10digits[$1]})) -eq 0 ]];
    then

        #echo "$variable1"
        #echo "$variable2"
        echo " true !!"

    elif [[ $((${indexOfcreateArray10digits[$2]} - ${indexOfmodifiedArray10digits[$1]})) -eq 1 ]];
    then

        echo " true !!"


    else
        echo " false!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! "

    fi
}
echo "difference:"$((${indexOfcreateArray10digits[14]} - ${indexOfmodifiedArray10digits[13]}))
connected_junks  14 13
echo "1:"${indexOfcreateArray10digits[14]}
echo "0:"${indexOfmodifiedArray10digits[13]}
=============== results 
difference:1
 false!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  # i have no idea why this is false 
1:1524058477
0:1524058395
============================================================






# for loop statement 
for i in seq 1 $last_file_index
do
    if [[ ! connected_junks $((i-1)) $i ]]; 
    then
        current_dir=$((current_dir+1))
        make_clip_dir $current_dir
    fi
    move_clip $i $current_dir 
done

# but won't works 
# only clip-1 folder was created and 00000.MTS moved into this folder 
#
```

########################### results error

```
/twoArrayCompare.sh: line 170: conditional binary operator expected
/twoArrayCompare.sh: line 170: syntax error near `$((i-1))'
/twoArrayCompare.sh: line 170: `    if [[ connected_junks $((i-1)) $i ]];
```

Comment: please see attached  image file  above "file info and metadata Regularity"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it on your sketch image. The idea of an algorithm is to follow your red arrows.

At first, you create the first directory and put the first clip file in there.

Then you can iterate from 2nd to last, and if there's an arrow to the previous item, you put that file into the same directory as the previous one. Otherwise if there's no arrow, you make a new directory.

Here's the meat of this program for you:

```
last_file_index=16

current_dir=1
make_clip_dir $current_dir
move_clip 0 $current_dir

for i in $(seq 1 $last_file_index)
do
    if ! connected_junks $((i-1)) $i
    then
        current_dir=$((current_dir+1))
        make_clip_dir $current_dir
    fi
    move_clip $i $current_dir       
done
```

You need to add `move_clip`, `make_clip_dir` and `connected_junks` functions to this.

The simplest is `make_clip_dir`:

```
function make_clip_dir {
    mkdir "clip-$1"
}
```

For `connected_junks` you can utilize your create/modified arrays and some `if` conditions, and then return 1 or 0.

For `move_clip` you need to format the index to form a name "000NN.MTS" and `mv` a source file to the new destination.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
please read added more detail explanation . and let me get more detail 
how to do .

Comment: problem is , 00000.MTS file also possible standalone file , not junked .
so maximum standalone MTS file not junked file can be exist as many as array length , in this case have make 16folders and put the each MTS files .. so some complex

Comment: This case is handled in my solution. Please read it and tell me if you don't understand something, I'll explain.

Comment: function make_clip_dir {
    mkdir "clip-$1"
}

Comment: function move_clip {
   mv ${indexOfcreateArrayFullFileNameWithExtension[$1]}  "clip-$1"
}

Comment: function connected_junks {
    if [[ $((${indexOfcreateArray10digits[$1]} - ${indexOfmodifiedArray10digits[$2]})) -eq 0 || $((${indexOfcreateArray10digits[$1]} - ${indexOfmodifiedArray10digits[$2]})) -eq 1 ]];
    then
        echo 0
    else
        echo 1
    fi
}

Comment: CNT=$((${#indexOfcreateArray10digits[*]}))
last_file_index=$CNT
current_dir=1
make_clip_dir $current_dir
move_clip 0 $current_dir

for i in seq 1 $last_file_index
do
    if [[ ! connected_junks $((i-1)) $i  ]];then
        current_dir=$((current_dir+1))
        make_clip_dir $current_dir
    fi
    move_clip $i $current_dir
done

Comment: i made three function and  for loop, but won't works

Comment: You're in the right direction.

From the obvious, try using "return" instead of "echo" in connected_junks like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431909/returning-a-boolean-from-a-bash-function

Also inside move_clip instead of `$(make_clip_dir $2)` just use "clip-$2"

Other than that learn how to debug by echo-ing intermediate variables, and post more separate questions on details.

Comment: and 
what this mean   move_clip 0 $current_dir ?

Comment: It moves file with index 0 (thus "00000.MTS") to current_dir=1 at this point, which is "clip-1", so it runs essentially `mv  "00000.MTS" "clip-1"`. In general it is supposed to move the file with index $1 into the existing directory with index $2 (the directory is pre-created by make_clip_dir).

Comment: Add lines like `echo "$variable1"` to print all your variables (also inside if-s and loops), and then you can find what your problem is. It now all depends on your array data being correct. I can explain how to make a fish rod, but I won't catch fish for you.

Comment: if you give me a fish ,then  i can study more much things inside of fish 
:-)

Comment: very strange ,  when i check on terminal , then i call  echo ${indexOfModifiedArrayFullFileNameWithExtension[1]}  then gave me the right "00001.MTS"  
BUT when i call  move_clip  1   1   THEN  was moved  00002.MTS into clip-1 folder .

Comment: Add more echo-s into the function :)

Comment: function  i have test  for connected_junk , it looks like  need iterator for array .  i have updated question field  .  i have no idea . for iterator

Comment: hello teacher. just remained only to implement for loop when i see just make problem on for loop you made :-).

Comment: hi. I have fixed the loop: it needs `$(...)` around seq, and no need to have `[[...]]` around connected_junks if (this fixes "conditional binary operator expected" error).

Also in your code you forgot to add "return 0" (after "echo true") and "return 1" (after "echo false"). See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431909/returning-a-boolean-from-a-bash-function

Comment: NICE !  THANKS YOU TEACHER ! WORKS PERFECT