# Test if file exists with a function in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following script, basically a function and an IF

```
file_exists() {

    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

if [[ $(file_exists "LICENSE") ]]; then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

But this code always returns NO. I know the IF statement expects to get a 0 to be true, but I don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: Also consider `-s` which will test `"True if file exists and has a size greater than zero."`

Comment: Your function does not write anything to stdout. Hence, `$(file_exists.....) is always empty. `[[ '' ]]` (i.e. on an empty string) takes by design the `else` branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the return value of a function in an if-statement, you do not need to wrap it in `[[]]`. You can replace

```
if [[ $(file_exists "LICENSE") ]]; then
```

with

```
if file_exists "LICENSE"; then
```

As for the convention of `0=true` and `1=false`, it's [not preferred to write them out explicitly in return statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840545/10615396). The body of your `file_exists` function can be reduced to

```
file_exists() {
    [ -f "$1" ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

IMHO if..else redundant here. Use your function like this:

```
file_exists $FILENAME && echo ok || echo notok
```