# Bash: How to use return from function in an if

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do use the return for a function in an if statement within bash.

I've come up with this very simple example which unfortunately fails.

```
always_false () {
        return 1
}

always_true () {
        return 0
}

if [ always_false ]
then
  echo 'it is true'
else
  echo 'it is false'
fi

if [ always_true ]
then
  echo 'it is true'
else
  echo 'it is false'
fi
```

Returns

> it is true

> it is true

I would expect it to return

> it is false

> it is true

The actual example of what i'm trying to achieve is checking the disk space for a particular directory. But I thought the simpler example would be better for understanding where i'm going wrong.

```
check_space () {
  spaceAvailable=$(($(stat -f --format="%a*%S" /path/to/dir)))
  fiftyGig=50000000000
  if [ $spaceAvailable -gt $fiftyGig ]
  then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}

if [ check_space ]
  echo 'do some things here'
else
  echo 'not enough disk space'
fi
```

I found [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840545/255940) that suggested I should be doing something like this:

```
always_false () {
        [[ 0 -gt 1 ]]
        return
}

always_true () {
        [[ 2 -gt 1 ]]
        return
}
```

But this did not seem to work and always came up true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your function like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_space () {
    spaceAvailable=$(($(stat -f --format="%a*%S" /path/to/dir))) || exit
    fiftyGig=50000000000
    ((spaceAvailable > fiftyGig))
}

if check_space
then
    echo 'do some things here'
else
    echo 'not enough disk space'
fi
```

Note that `if [ check_space ]` does not do what you think it does: The function `check_space` won't be called at all. The `check_space` is merely a string for the `test` (`[`) command. `[ string ]` checks for the length of the *string*: If the *string* is non-empty then it will return `true`, and return `false` otherwise.

You may also consider passing the path and size as an argument to the function:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_space () {
    spaceAvailable=$(($(stat -f --format="%a*%S" "$1"))) || exit
    ((spaceAvailable > "$2"))
}

if check_space /path/to/dir 50000000000
then
    echo 'do some things here'
else
    echo 'not enough disk space'
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the brackes:

```bash
if always_false
then
  echo 'it is true'
else
  echo 'it is false'
fi

if always_true
then
  echo 'it is true'
else
  echo 'it is false'
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

To further your understanding of the answers, at a bash prompt enter `help if`

```
$ help if
if: if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
    Execute commands based on conditional.
...
```

Note that the first argument is "COMMANDS", not "[ COMMANDS ]" -- `if` executes "COMMANDS" and branches based on the *exit status*:

- exit status zero is "true"
- any other status is "false"

You can think of `[...]` (and `[[...]]` and `((...))`) as the command to run: "what's the exit status of that conditional command?"

---

Note that bash includes `true` and `false` as *builtin commands*:

```bash
if true; then echo "always true"; else echo "this is not printed"; fi
```