# Bash : how can a function return a value when stdout has been closed?

Tags: bash

I have the following at the beginning of a number of bash scripts :

```
# Not an interactive use.
if [[ ! -t 0 && ! -t 1 ]]; then
    #echo "The script is not called interactively.  Close stdout and stderr."
    # Close standard output file descriptor
    exec 1<&-
    # Close standard error file descriptor
    exec 2<&-
fi
```

This prevents the script from writing to /var/log/cron.log when called by CRON.

There is however a undesired side-effect : the value echoed by a function contained in the script can no longer be read by the calling line in the script.  For instance :

```
#! /bin/bash

# Not an interactive use.
if [[ ! -t 0 && ! -t 1 ]]; then
    #echo "The script is not called interactively.  Close stdout and stderr."
    # Close standard output file descriptor
    exec 1<&-
    # Close standard error file descriptor
    exec 2<&-
fi

function myTest() {
    echo true
}

if [[ $(myTest) == true ]]; then
    echo Test is true;
fi
```

I found a workaround using a variable set by the function and then read by the script after the function has run.  But this is ugly.

```
declare gResult;

function myTest() {
    gResult=true;
}

myTest
if [[ "$gResult" == true ]]; then
    echo Test is true;
fi
```

Comment: Im not sure what your question is. Are you asking if the function can write to `STDOUT`, or about the return value of the function?

Comment: take `echo` for example: `echo` never checks if stdout is a tty or not. it just does not care. if users want to discard the output they just `echo ... > /dev/null`. let the users make their decisions.

Comment: It seems to work for me. Note that you will not see the results from `echo Test is true`, since standard out has been closed.

Comment: This is a very good educational question!

Comment: Why do you want to close stdout? This is in particularily odd, since you shortly after write to stdout.

Comment: If a function just needs to return a boolean value then the easiest way to do it is to explicitly `return 0` for true and `return 1` for false.  Testing the return value is then simply `if myTest; then ...`.  See [Returning a boolean from a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431909/4154375).

Comment: @user1934428 : I close stdout because in the context of CRON it writes to /var/log/cron.log and I don't want it (it causes logwatch sends me useless emails).  What is odd is the way to return a string from a function in a bash script : use echo.  It conflicts, by design with my first constraint.

Comment: @pjh : good suggestion, it works.  One caveat : it only works if you don't need to return a string.  Still : you made my day.

Comment: @ballatom : If you don't write the output to be written to cron.log, why don't you redirect **in the crontab** stdout and stderr to a file of your choice? You could even redirect it to /dev/null, but then you have no practical way for debugging, if something goes wron, so I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @user1934428 : I didn't think about it.  It seems to be the best solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How do you know?

```
if [[ $(myTest) == true ]]; then
    echo Test is true;
fi
```

If the `echo` command executed, you wouldn't see it because standard output is closed.

So the lack of output from the above command doesn't prove that the `$(myTest)` command substitution isn't capturing the `"true"` output.

When I run the following script, the termination status is `3`, though no output is seen!

```
#!/bin/bash

# Not an interactive use.
exec 1<&-
# Close standard error file descriptor
exec 2<&-

function myTest() {
    echo true
}

if [[ $(myTest) == true ]]; then
    echo Test is true;
    exit 3
fi

exit 0
```

Think about it: command substitution works by redirecting standard output. It doesn't care what the original standard output is, or that it is closed!

Command substitution works fine in scripts that have been redirected to a file, pipe or `/dev/null`; why wouldn't it work under a closed standard output.

Comment: Well, my test stopped returning true when I started closing stdout.  It works if I use a variable instead of echo.  It works if I use return instead of echo.  So I think that I can safely assume that closing stdout prevents the script from capturing what is echoed by the function.

Comment: @ballatom How do you know it stopped returning true? You seem to be using `echo Test is true` to report the value, but *that* part (not the function return) will fail because of stdout being closed. Since `$( )` reassigns stdout of its contents, it doesn't matter whether stdout is closed in the parent context; it gets reassigned no matter what its state was outside of the `$( )`.