# Using functions in Bash

Tags: bash, function, shell

Is this the correct syntax for parameterized functions?

```
#!/bin/bash

twoPow()
{
    prod=1
    for((i=0;i<$1;i++));
    do
        prod=$prod*2
    done
    return prod
}

echo "Enter a number"
read num
echo `twoPow $num`
```

Output:

bash sample.sh

Enter a number

3

sample.sh: line 10: return: prod: numeric argument required

**Part 2:**

I removed the return, but what should I do if I want to run multiple times and store results like below? How can I make this work?

```
#!/bin/bash

tp1=1
tp2=1

twoPow()
{
    for((i=0;i<$1;i++));
    do
        $2=$(($prod*2))
    done
}

twoPow 3 tp1
twoPow 2 tp2
echo $tp1+$tp2
```

Comment: change return prod to echo $prod and re-try.
ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742783/returning-value-from-called-function-in-shell-script

Answer (score 4):

In Bash scripts you can't return values to the calling code.

The simplest way to emulate "returning" a value as you would in other languages is to set a global variable to the intended result.

Fortunately in bash all variables are global by default. Just try outputting the value of `prod` after calling that function.

Comment: This works:

`#!/bin/bash

prod=1

twoPow()
{
 for((i=0;i<$1;i++)); 
 do
  prod=$(($prod*2))
 done
}

echo "Enter a number"
read num
twoPow $num
echo $prod`

Comment: What should I do if I want to call it multiple times and store result?

Answer (score 0):

A sample Bash function definition and call with a few parameters and return values. It may be useful and it works.

```
#!/bin/sh

## Define function
function sum()
{

 val1=$1

 val2=$2

 val3=`expr $val1 + $val2`

 echo $val3

}

# Call function with two parameters and it returns one parameter.
ret_val=$(sum 10 20)
echo $ret_val
```

Comment: `expr` is not needed for arithmetic anymore; use `val3=$(( val1 + val2 ))` instead.