# Shell script : Count returned from function is not correct

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In the below shell script I am connecting to DB and getting the count value.
In the below code I am not getting the correct count value. Instead it is returning 185 (random int value)
but the actual count value which is supposed to be returned is 2233.
If I replace `return` with `echo`, it prints the correct 2233 value. But `alertCount` variable is assigned 0 value.

```
findAlertCount(){
(
count=$(sqlplus -s  ${DBA_ORACLE_USER}/${DBA_ORACLE_PWORD}@${ORACLE_SID} <<END
#connect ${DBA_ORACLE_USER}/${DBA_ORACLE_PWORD}@${ORACLE_SID}
set serveroutput on
set linesize 1000
set heading off
set feedback off
SELECT count(1)
FROM mytable
WHERE mycolumn IS NOT NULL;
exit;
END
)
return "$count"
)
}

findAlertCount
alertCount=$?
echo "alertCount" $alertCount
```

**//This prints 185 if return is used. And prints 0 if echo is used.**

Comment: Don't use the return value of a function to pass data. It is solely for indicating if the function has succeeded or failed.

Comment: There's a very good answer on how to return from a shell function here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8743103/5950

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `printf` and retrieve the final value of "count" in your function as stdout.

```
#!/bin/sh


findAlertCount()
{
    count=2233
    printf "$count"
}

alertCount=$(findAlertCount)

printf "alertCount $alertCount\n"
```

Additionally I observe you are using parenthesis `()` to invoke the body of the function as a subshell. If the intent is merely to delineate the commands as a set or list perhaps try brackets `{}` instead so the value of count is accessible to the rest of the program.

Comment: Good point about the subshell but I don't really see the advantage of making the variable global - if anything, I'd suggest using `local` to reduce its scope.

Comment: `local` is not part of POSIX; the user may not be using `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, simplify. And use `set -x` to see what's going on. Here I'm replacing your SQL command with a simple echo to simulate your SQL (because I don't have access to Oracle):

```
set -x
findAlertCount(){
(
    count=$(echo 2233)
    return "$count"
)
}

findAlertCount
alertCount=$?
echo "alertCount" $alertCount
```

When run, that prints:

```
+ findAlertCount
++ echo 2233
+ count=2233
+ return 2233
+ alertCount=185
+ echo alertCount 185
alertCount 185
```

However, rewriting it slightly to this:

```
set -x
findAlertCount(){
    count=$(echo 2233)
    echo "$count"
}

alertCount=$(findAlertCount)
echo "alertCount" $alertCount
```

and running it we get the expected result:

```
++ findAlertCount
+++ echo 2233
++ count=2233
++ echo 2233
+ alertCount=2233
+ echo alertCount 2233
alertCount 2233
```