# Unable to extract value from Unix bash array if using functions

Tags: arrays, bash, function, shell

I am trying to extract the value from a bash array. It works fine if it is the following code -

```
### stk3.sh 
#!bin/bash
declare -x -A my_ids
my_ids[cat]=100
my_ids[dog]=200
id_key=${1:-cat}  ## setting default
echo "Id key is :${id_key}"
id_no=${my_ids[$id_key]}
echo "Value is ### ${id_no}"
```

if I execute the above I get the desired output  -
(saved the above script in stk3.sh)

```
./stk3.sh dog
       Id key is :dog
       Value is ### 200
```

Now, when I use functions, I am unable to get the desired output. Defined the function in one script (stk1.sh) and calling the function to get the value from a specific key from another script (stk2.sh)

```
### stk1.sh
#!/bin/bash
declare -x -A my_ids
function my_ids {
  my_ids[cat]=100
  my_ids[dog]=200
  echo "Length of Array :${#my_ids[*]}"
  echo "*** Now printing the contents of the Array ...."
  for x in "${!my_ids[@]}"
  do
    printf "$x  ${my_ids[$x]} \n"
  done
}
my_ids


function get-value {
  printf "$1\n"
  if [[ -n "$1" ]]
    then
    id_no=${my_ids[$id_key]}
  fi
}
```

When calling the function using, I am NOT getting the desired results-
Here is my stk2.sh

```
### stk2.sh 
#!/bin/bash
 
source stk1.sh
id_key=${1:-cat}  ## setting default
echo "Id key is :${id_key}"
id_no=$(get-value $id_key)
echo "Value is ### ${id_no}"
```

Output after executing skt2.sh, As you can see it is not returning the value of id _no, which in this case should be 200:

```
./stk2.sh dog
Length of Array :2
*** Now printing the contents of the Array ....
dog  200 
cat  100 
Id key is :dog
Value is ### dog
```

Comment: `get-value` is missing `}`? `As you can see it is not` I cannot see that - the output has `Value is ### dog`

Comment: I think the missing `}` is a copy&paste error, when I add it, the scripts run as described. I have proposed an edit that fixes that and clears up what (I assume) is the expected outcome.

Comment: While assignments in a function modify global variables by default, it's a *different* global variable in a command substitution than if you execute the function directly in the current shell. (I.e., `get-value $id_key` and `$(get-value $id_key)` assign to different `id_no` values.)

Comment: Arrays can't be exported; you don't get the effect of `-x` when you use `declare -A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get-value` assigns the value of `id_no` and outputs the input. But then your main script assigns `id_no` to hold the output of `get-value`, which is the key you pass in. Not the behaviour you're looking for.

Try

```bash
function get-value {
    printf '%s\n' "${my_ids[$1]:?"no such key"}"
}
```

`${var:?error-message}` emits the error message if var is null or unset and produces an error status. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Then the main script can have

```bash
if ! id_no=$(get-value "$id_key"); then
    echo "try a different key"
    exit 1
fi
do-something-with "$id_no"
```

Answer (score 2):

`id_no` is set within the `get-value()` function call, and since you haven't defined `id_no` as 'local' to the function, the new value of `id_no` is automatically available to the calling/parent process.

What you want to do is call the function without trying to capture its output, eg:

```
$ cat stk2.sh 
#!/bin/bash

source stk1.sh
id_key=${1:-cat}  ## setting default
echo "Id key is :${id_key}"
get-value $id_key
echo "Value is ### ${id_no}"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not directly possible. You can't return something that is not an exit code from a function in bash. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8743103/21164658) discusses alternatives.

Your line `id_no=$(get-value $id_key)` in stk2.sh captures all output from that command (which you start in a subshell by using `$(...)`), which in this case is determined by the line `printf "$1\n"` in stk1.sh.

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655377) is another insightful discussion about return values of bash functions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your get-value function ...

```
function get-value {
  printf "$1\n"
  if [[ -n "$1" ]]
    then
    id_no=${my_ids[$id_key]}
  fi
}
```

... prints its first argument ("$1"), then, if the latter is non-empty, assigns the value of `my_ids[$id_key]` to variable `id_no`.

Which raises a few questions :

1. why does your `get-value` function manipulates variables which were not passed as arguments?  `get-value` is invoked inside a *command substitution* statement : it runs in a subshell, with a copy of the parent environment.  Sure, it *will* be able to access `id_key`'s value, because `id_key` happened to be defined earlier in `stk2.sh`, but then what's the use of checking whether first function argument ("$1") is empty or not?
2. your assignment statement concerning `id_no` will *not* be reflected in the parent environment.  It will exist only during the subshell run of `get-value`.
3. you're misusing the command substitution feature. `$(get-value $id_key)` will be replaced by whatever gets printed to STDOUT during the subshell run. Since your function does `printf "$1\n"`, it actually returns (as the substituted string) the value of its first argument.  So if `id_key` is "cat", `$(get-value $id_key)` returns "cat".

---

To sum it up (assuming `stk2.sh` invocation as `./stk2.sh dog`:

```
id_key=${1:-cat}  ## setting default     id_key is set to "dog"

id_no=$(get-value $id_key)               within subshell:
                                            * print "dog\n"
                                            * id_no=200
                                         back to initial environment:
                                            * id_no="dog"

echo "Value is ### ${id_no}"             prints "Value is ### dog"
```

---

Simple suggestion:

```
function get-value {
  if [[ -n "$1" ]]
    then
      echo ${my_ids[$1]}
  fi  
}
```

Hope that helps.