# How do I test if a string starts with another in bash?

Tags: bash, git-bash

Very similar but not duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2172367/57883

I'm in Git Bash 3.1 (at least that's what comes up in the prompt when I type bash inside git bash.

and `$ test [["DEV-0" == D*]] || echo 'fail'` prints fail.

`if [['DEV-0-1'  == DEV* ]]; then echo "yes";` says `[[DEV-0-1: command not found`
I'm trying to test if `git branch` returns something that starts with DEV. but I can't seem to apply the answer. is it because all my attempts are using a string literal on the left instead of a variable value?

I've also tried it on ideone http://ideone.com/3IyEND

and no luck.
It's been ~14 years since I was good with a linux prompt.

What am I missing for a string starts with test in bash?

Comment: You have syntax errors you need spaces on both sides of [[ and ]] ;

Comment: `if [['DEV-0-1' == DEV* ]] ; then echo "yes"; ` also says `[[DEV-0-1: command not found`

Comment: ah! `if [[ 'DEV-0-1' == DEV* ]] ; then echo "yes";` appears to work.

Comment: what's wrong with the `test ||` syntax? same thing?

Comment: @Maslow `[[` is a bash-builtin testing syntax, and `test` or `[` is a traditional UNIX command (which is important -- you always need a space between the name of a command and its arguments, after all). You use one or the other; trying to combine them as in `test [[ ...` makes no sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You missed a space there:

```
 if [[ 'DEV-0-1' == DEV* ]]; then echo "yes"; fi
      ^^
```

Comment: Speedy Gonzales is... Indian =)

Comment: hehe.. I've hit this error enough times to see it right away ;-)

Comment: @Maslow pattern-matching is only supported by `[[`. If you want POSIX, you have to use `case..esac` or `[ -z "${var##dev*}" ]`.

Comment: @Maslow When you do `D*` it's going to be expanded by the shell *before* comparison. `test [[ $a == D* ]] || echo 'test fail'` is not going to work. That's why you get that error.

Comment: so I kinda like the `test condition ||` syntax is there a way to use that test deal for a string starts with condition?

Comment: @Maslow You can my example here: http://ideone.com/sC3bbm . The part `${a:0:1}` basically gets the substring of `a` starting from index 0 of length `1` and it's compared. Same way you can get different length substrings with different lengths. E.g. `${a:0:2}` will give the first 2 letters in `a`.

Answer (score 7):

I'd probably rather do the check like this:

```
s1=DEV-0-1
s2=DEV

if [ "${s1:0:${#s2}}" == "$s2" ]; then
  echo "yes"
fi
```