# How I can change string by mask in bash scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

how I can change strings to another by mask?
I want to see something like this code:

```
if [ "$PANEL_SOURCE_COMPONENT_NAME" == "something-*"]; then
                    COMPONENTO_NAME="newline-*"
else
                    COMPONENTO_NAME="$PANEL_SOURCE_COMPONENT_NAME"
fi
```

of course, this code is not working. How I can do something similar?
Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418149/how-do-i-test-if-a-string-starts-with-another-in-bash.

Comment: I do not understand well your question but if what you want is to avoid $ in your string,  you can write: `'$PANEL_SOURCE_COMPONENT_NAME'` or `"\$PANEL_SOURCE_COMPONENT_NAME"`

Comment: @juanmajmjr, i want to change variable, which begins from "something-", and include there another begining - "newline-". For example, if variable was "something-ololol-9" I want to see "newline-ololo-9" there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if [[ "$PANEL_SOURCE_COMPONENT_NAME" = "something-"* ]]; then
    COMPONENTO_NAME="$(echo "$PANEL_SOURCE_COMPONENT_NAME" | sed 's/something-\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]\)/newline-\1/g')"
else
    COMPONENTO_NAME="$PANEL_SOURCE_COMPONENT_NAME"
fi
```

For example:

```
[~]$ TEST=something-that-is-long
[~]$ echo "$TEST" | sed 's/something-\([a-zA-Z0-9_]\)/newline-\1/g'
newline-that-is-long
[~]$
```

Note that the `*` must be placed outside of the quotes for Bash to do a glob-match.