# How to check if a string begins with a particular string>

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to check if a string begins with a particular string. But the below code is not working.

//    set @test_date = '123456'

```
if [[ $var == "set @test_date =*"  ]]; then
      echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

I found the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172352/in-bash-how-can-i-check-if-a-string-begins-with-some-value), but it not working for me

Thanks

Comment: Fwiw, `[[ $var == set\ @test_date\ =*  ]]` works. I'm not sure enough of the ins and outs to explain the how & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 [[ "$var" == "set @test_date ="*  ]] && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

`*` needs to be out of quotes for shell to expand.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you are looking for, the following is generally the most robust:

```
[[ "${var:0:len_of_sub}" == "$substring" ]] && echo "${var:0:len_of_sub} matches $substring"
```

Further, you can adjust the beginning index `0` here, to start the match at any location. There are a number of way to do this, so you should consider all the answers. Another favorite (only works with the compound command `[[` is:

```
[[ "$var" =~  "$substring" ]]
```

That will match substring anywhere within `$var`