# Checking if variable starts with another variable in bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash, variables, comparison

Similar to this >> [In bash, how can I check if a string begins with some value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172352/in-bash-how-can-i-check-if-a-string-begins-with-some-value), but not duplicated.

I have two arrays, and for each string inside the first one, I wanna check whether the strings in the second one start with the string from the first one or not.

```
array1=("test1","test2","test3");
array2=("test1 etc","test1 nanana","test2 zzz","test3 abracadabra");

for i in "${!array1[@]}"; do
  for j in "${!array2[@]}"; do 
    if [[ "${array1[i]}" == "${array2[j]}*" ]]; then  
      echo "array1[$i] and arry2[$j] initial matches!";
      fi; 
    done; 
done
```

I tried many conditions inside if, such as:

```
if [[ "${array1[i]}" == "${array2[j]*}" ]]
if [[ "${array1[i]}" == "${array2[j]}*" ]]
if [[ "${array1[i]}" = "${array2[j]*}" ]]
if [[ "${array1[i]}" = "${array2[j]}*" ]]
```

Also without quotes, braces, and so on, all with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some errors in your code, first of all, array declaration in bash: if you don't put spaces you have only one element. Remember to always print the variables before trying anything else on them. 
From the bash docs:

> ARRAY=(value1 value2 ... valueN)
>
> Each value is then in the form of [indexnumber=]string. The index
>   number is optional. If it is supplied, that index is assigned to it;
>   otherwise the index of the element assigned is the number of the last
>   index that was assigned, plus one. This format is accepted by declare
>   as well. If no index numbers are supplied, indexing starts at zero.

To cycle array elements:

```
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done
```

Here is a code snippet:

```
array1=(test1 test2 test3);
array2=(test1 etc "test1 nanana" test2zzz test3 abracadabra);
for word1 in "${array1[@]}"; do
    for word2 in "${array2[@]}"; do 
        echo "w1=$word1, w2=$word2"
        if [[ ${word2} == ${word1}* ]]; then   
            echo "$word1 and $word2 initial matches!";
        fi;                   
    done;                         
done
```

---

After the comment by the OP I realised that He was trying to use indices, to do that you have to use the "$" also for the indices "i" and "j". 
Here is a working solution:

```
for i in "${!array1[@]}"; do
    for j in "${!array2[@]}"; do    
        echo "${array1[$i]} ${array2[$j]}"
        if [[ ${array2[$j]} == ${array1[$i]}* ]]; then
            echo "$array1[$i] and $array2[$j] initial matches!";
        fi; 
    done; 
done
```

Comment: My code is longer; I am using "readarray -t array1" to set the arrays with command outputs, so I declared the arrays in wrong way but only here in the question - my fault. Also, I used "!" in the front of the array because I wanted "i" and "j" to be the indexes. But your solution did work good as well. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realised that you are trying to use the indices, while I think that my first solution is better with bash I update the answer to include the one you were trying to implement.

Comment: perfect, just got another mistake in my code. Thank you very much.