# How do you create a Docker image that takes in the whole file system?

Tags: docker

I don't have `bat` on one of my servers, but I do have `docker` so rather than trying to extract the files I was thinking of creating a simple docker image like

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache bat
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/bat" ]
```

Then run it

```
docker run --rm -it  -w /w -v ${PWD}:/w trajano/bat .bash_profile
```

But what if I want to do something like

```
docker run --rm -it  -w /w -v ${PWD}:/w trajano/bat /etc/passwd
```

Is that possible?

I was thinking of something like changing the image to

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache bat
COPY bat.sh /bat
RUN chmod 700 /bat
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bat" ]
```

bat.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/bat (some magic here)
```

Then run as

```
docker run --rm -it  -v /:/host trajano/bat /etc/passwd
```

but not sure what that *some magic here* would look like

Comment: Just bind-mount whatever you want to `bat` into the container.

Comment: (Yes, that can be the entire host filesystem; yes, you can add a `docker run -u root` option to run as root; yes, absolutely nothing stops you from editing the host's `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/sudoers` this way.)

Answer (score 0):

I did a simplistic sh script which [checked the first character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172352/in-bash-how-can-i-check-if-a-string-begins-with-some-value)

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache bat
COPY bat.sh /bat
RUN chmod 700 /bat
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bat" ]
```

bat.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
beginswith() { case $2 in "$1"*) true;; *) false;; esac; }
if [ ! "$1" ]
then
    /usr/bin/bat
elif beginswith "/" "$1"
then
    /usr/bin/bat /host$1
else
    /usr/bin/bat /host$HPWD/$1
fi
```

And to alias it

```
alias bat="command docker run --rm -e HPWD=`pwd` -v /:/host:ro -it trajano/bat"
```

Code in https://github.com/trajano/docker-bat.git

It does not handle multiple paths or command line parameters but it does what I need it to do.

Though in the end I did this

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.local/bin
curl -sL https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases/download/v0.19.0/bat-v0.19.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.gz | tar  zxf - -C $HOME/.local/bin bat-v0.19.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/bat
mv $HOME/.local/bin/bat-v0.19.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/bat $HOME/.local/bin 
rmdir $HOME/.local/bin/bat-v0.19.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/
```