# Bash script to detect arguments with a dash

Tags: bash, alpine-linux

I'm trying to make a script that's supposed to tell me which argument stars with a dash. I looked at [In Bash, how can I check if a string begins with some value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172352/in-bash-how-can-i-check-if-a-string-begins-with-some-value), but the accepted answer didn't work.

Here is the script:

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
    if [[ $var == -* ]]
    then
        echo "$var starts with dash"
    fi
done
```

When I run it I just get this:

```
~$ ./dash_test.sh -dash no_dash --two -one
-dash
no_dash
--two
-one
```

That `if [[ $var == -* ]]` doesn't appear to work, which is what was suggested in that question I linked.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`? You have no shebang in the script; what happens when you run `bash dash_test.sh -dash no_dash --two -one`?

Comment: Yep, that's it, I forgot Alpine uses Ash, I think by default